# Retrieve user access TOKEN from WSO2 Api Manager

Tags: api, wso2, token

I have a problem with retrieving the end-user access token from wso2, I need it to invoke the API that retrieves the list of all applications in the Wso2 Api Manager Store. I did a research on this site: 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/#!/operations#ApplicationCollection#applicationsGet, 
but I don't know how I can generate user token (not application token).

On the other side I found the temporary solution, that returns a list of all applications invoking the API login, and then API that returns the app list found on this link: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Store+APIs, but it shows me only how to do it with a session authentication, NOT with JWT token auth.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the getting started guide[1]. For a token generation, you need client id and secret. To get that you need to register an application.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/#guide

Comment: thanks for the answer, I know how to generate the token for the application, but I need a carbon user token, not application user token, because with the application token I cant invoke get the list of all application names, only as a user (ex: admin) I can see which applications are registered in wso2 api manager store.

Comment: In the above doc you can see the token call has user credentials. `grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin`. That means it generates a user token.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand all very well. The token that I get with call                   curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=apim:subscribe" -H "Authorization: Basic SGZFbDFqSlBkZzV0YnRyeGhBd3liTjA1UUdvYTpsNmMwYW9MY1dSM2Z3ZXpIaGM3WG9HT2h0NUFh" https://localhost:8243/token         ,      I can only research for the APIs that I registered on with this specific application that I already passed in the call, I tried to do the query that returns all apps that I registered but it gives me  "Unauthenticated request"

Comment: with the token you said before I can't retrieve the list of applications,   https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/#!/operations#ApplicationCollection#applicationsGet I have the same problem

Comment: you were right, i needed first to register User (login user, not application user), with response I get cliendId and cliendSecret, that I use them to generate user token, then I can get the list of application. thanks again @Bee